BFGS algorithm finding almost good parameters but not converging with scipy.minimize()
I am estimating an Interval Regression model. I wrote my likelihood function (see intreg, STATA) as stated bellow, and compared my results with STATA. I am finding almost exactly (within 0.001) same parameters as STATA but the BFGS algorithm seems still not to converge.
I still get the following message :
  message: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
  success: False
   status: 2
      fun: 26435.40918822449
        x: [ 7.379e+00 -6.967e-02 ...  2.149e-01  4.295e-01]
      nit: 94
      jac: [-4.883e-04  0.000e+00 ... -2.441e-04  4.883e-04]
 hess_inv: [[ 3.566e-04 -7.314e-05 ... -1.261e-04 -1.775e-06]
            [-7.314e-05  5.599e-05 ...  3.216e-05  5.660e-07]
            ...
            [-1.261e-04  3.216e-05 ...  4.981e-04  1.297e-06]
            [-1.775e-06  5.660e-07 ...  1.297e-06  8.380e-06]]
     nfev: 4235
     njev: 121 


The log-likelihood function:
def log_likelihood(params, x, y_lower, y_upper):
    beta = params[:-1]
    sigma = np.abs(params[-1])  

    z_upper = (y_upper - np.dot(x, beta)) / sigma
    z_lower = (y_lower - np.dot(x, beta)) / sigma
    
    epsilon = 1e-10
    ll_interval = np.sum(np.log(np.clip(norm.cdf(z_upper) - norm.cdf(z_lower), epsilon, None)))

    log_likelihood = ll_interval
    
    return -log_likelihood  


and the command that I use to minimize it:
initial_params = np.concatenate([np.zeros(X.shape[1]), [1.0]])
result = minimize(log_likelihood, initial_params, args=(X, y_lower, y_upper), method='BFGS', options={'disp':True})


Does someone has an idea of why the algorithm seems to converge but still giving message that it is not?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect that it is something to do with the way that ll_interval is being computed leading to not quite catastrophic cancellation. Enough to make the optimiser unhappy but not enough to prevent it getting fairly close to a half decent answer. You are probably looking for somewhere that a small number is computed as the difference of two rather large ones (given the error msg).

The default gtol value (which can be passed through the options dict) was too high and needed to be lowered.
